# How to add query scope on lazy eager loading

Tags: php, laravel, eager-loading

I'm trying to get a query scope working when retrieving the user Tasks / comments.
Here is how my query normally looks:

```
if ($request->is('tasks')) {

    $user->load([
        'tasks'    => function ($query) {
            $query->where('completed', 0)->latest();
        },
        'comments' => function ($query) {
            $query->latest();
        },
    ]);
}
```

My added query scope in the model:

```
public function scopeInCompleted($query) {

   $query->where('completed', 0);
}
```

How do I add this scope on my query?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to call it in the same way:

```
'tasks'    => function ($query) {
    $query->InCompleted()->latest();
},
```

Comment: What if the 'comments' relationship has the same complete query? Is it possible to add 'comments' after 'Tasks'?

Comment: @Dax Which model did you add `scopeInCompleted()` to?

Comment: To my 'Task' Model only

Comment: @Dax Then if you want to use it will your `comments` you will have to add it to your `Comment` model as well and then add it to your eager load constraints for 'comments'.